# Project Transfer executes but target project is still blank

Tags: mysql, svn, enterprise-architect

My current set up for EA is hosted on MySQL DBMS and has version control with Subversion. I attempted to do a DBMS to File project transfer to one on a desktop which complete's successfully. However, when I open the target project it seems as if the source project did not transfer over at all. Has anyone come across this issue before?

Below is my logfile:

```
+--------------------------------------------
| Data Transfer model log file
| Generated by Enterprise Architect
| Source DBMS: MYSQL
| Target DBMS: JET
| Created On : Saturday, 18 February, 2017
+--------------------------------------------
2017-02-18 01:18:00  Removing data in: usystables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's a missing table `usystables`. You need to recover it from some blank EAP file. See also this post: [enter link description here](http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,24923.msg199587.html#msg199587)

P.S. Or it's what Geert posted just a few seconds ago ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have security set on the target model?
That can effectively cause this type of issue.

Solution is to remove security from the target model (or start with a blank target project)

Comment: Geert, if security is turned on, EA asks for user/password (just tried it). So that's likely not the reason.